# "No" vs. "not" for negation

Tags: nouns, negation, no-not

I am not clear about the use of *no* and *not* . I have come across two sentences
like:

> - All I asked was time, *not* money.
> - I met this person about a month ago. I remember his name, what he was wearing and his hair texture, but *no* face.

In sentence 1 *not* is used whereas in sentence 2, *no* is used. Why so? Can anybody explain?

Comment: "I met this person about a month ago. I remember his name, what he was wearing and his hair texture, but no face." This usage of 'no' is also wrong. It should be "...but not his face." If he had no face, then he'd be a strange looking individual.

Comment: @Ronan: no, "no face" means "I remember no face". That doesn't mean there _was_ no face, but if there was one, I do not remember it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of **no** seems to make the following noun behave as a mass noun. There is no difference between regular mass nouns like *time*, *money* or *water*, and nouns that are usually countable in sentences like (the first to are common mass nouns, the second two are normally countable):

> I have no money.
>   I have no time.
>   I have no clue.
>   I have no idea.

When we form the same sentences with not, the last two examples require the use of an article (as we would normally expect with countable nouns):

> I have not a clue.
>   I have not an idea.

They are correct, although we would normally use *do* in these negative sentences:

> I do not have a clue.
>   I do not have an idea.

But for the first two sentences, that is very awkward:

> *I have not a money.
>   *I have not a time.

Also without an article they sound awkward:

> I have not money.
>   I have not time.

If we employ *do* again, however, nothing is wrong:

> I do not have money.
>   I do not have time.

So, in short, if you use an article, you can use **not**. If there is no article, you can use **no**, or you can use **not** for mass nouns. When you use **not**, it is best to construct the sentence as a normal negative, with the auxiliary *do*.

---

But, this does *not* explain "I asked for time, not money!
Indeed, it doesn't.

In that sentence, the second phrase is a shortened for of the negation of the first one.

If we were to write it out full, it would look like this:

> I asked for time, I did not ask for money.

Or the awkward version without *do*:

> I asked for time, I asked not for money.

Since money is a mass noun, this follows what I described before. 
It's just that when shortening the sentence, it may not be obvious at first.

Comment: the above doesn't explain the use of _no_ in second sentence. Please can you explain?

Comment: Your second sentence is "I remember [..] no face", which is equivalent to " I have no money", just like the first examples I gave. It makes _face_ act like a mass noun.

Answer (score 0):

I have another understanding on the use of *not* and *no*.  *Not* is used with a verb. i.e: do not, have not.

So, in the first sentence, "All I asked was time, not money." I think it's short of "All I asked was time I did not ask for money."

In the second sentence, I would agree with Ronan, that *not* should be used. The sentence can be re-written as:

"I met this person about a month ago. I remember his name, what he was wearing and his hair texture, but I do not remember his face."

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the first example negates the verb without the auxiliary do as in JFK's famous phrase "Ask not what your country can do for you..." instead of the usual "Do not ask what...", whereas the second example negates the noun phrase "money". Also, note that "I remember W, X, Y, but Z." where W, X and Y are un-negated noun phrases, and Z is negated, which is precisely why it needs a "but" and not an "and" since there is a contradiction being expressed.